# Sync birthdays from Facebook to Android contacts

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, contacts, sync, facebook

Many people want to have their Facebook contacts synced with their Android contacts, including information such as birthday and so on.

I have the official Facebook app installed on my Android 2.3.3 phone and it automatically syncs the email address and profile picture from Facebook. But it doesn't sync the birthdays.

So I chose the iCal approach so that you export your Facebook calendar and import it to the Google calendar (web interface).

But some days ago, someone told me that you can sync your Facebook birthdays with your Android contacts simply by adding the account in your "Accounts" settings. Is this true? How does it work? For me, it just syncs the photo and the email, as I've said.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i'm aware, you can't actually sync the birthdays to your contacts. It is however possible to sync your Facebook Events (including birthdays) to your Android calendar. All you need to do is add your Facebook Calendar to your Google Calendar. You can find out how to do this [here](http://lifehacker.com/5391880/add-your-facebook-events-to-google-calendar)

Comment: Thanks, using the calendar export is what I've done already. But someone showed me that he has synced the birthdays to his Android contacts. Does it depend on the Android version, maybe?

Comment: It seems to, although i am running 4.0.4 on a Galaxy S3 and a field for 'birthdays' doesn't exist for contacts. Perhaps it was removed?

Comment: Are you sure? When editing a contact, you can choose "Add date" or something like this and then choose between anniversaries and birthdays, can't you?

Comment: My apologies, you are correct. 'Add Event' features a birthday field.

Comment: After further investigation, it appears this is only possible to do using a paid app called FContactSync.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I thought as well. Nevertheless it was explained to me that you can use the built-in "Accounts" to sync that. But apparently, nobody seems to know about it. Maybe he used an additional sync-app without knowing.